# Initial value for index[3:0] is ignored for synthesis

Tags: vhdl

My code works perfectly under Windows quartus. But when I am using hdl designer (Siemens) under Centos, I have the following problem.
There is no info about this "compile_initial_values" switch from from the internet.

```
signal index : integer range 0 to 10 := 0;
```

---

```
 *Warning: [45702]: Initial value for index[3:0] is ignored for synthesis. 
To allow initial value for synthesis, please set the attribute "allow_init_val" 
in HDL or enable the global support for initial value synthesis 
through "compile_initial_values" switch.*
```

Comment: What are you asking? The warning tells you what to do - either set an attribute in VHDL or enable an option in the software configuration - there should be some generic information where these switches are located even if this special one is not mentioned.

Answer (score 3):

Very few FPGA fabrics can set registers on configuration, so the initial values cannot be expressed in the bitstream.

The reason for this is that most applications will have a separate "application reset" signal that can be used to load the initial values independent from FPGA configuration, so allowing initial value load through configuration would only needlessly enlarge the bitstream and require extra switching logic that becomes part of the timing budget.

The compiler can generate that logic for you, but it will be connected to an internally generated signal that is otherwise unreachable for you, so you can only reset the FPGA by reloading the configuration.

Usually people will write the reset logic as explicit HDL, which gives the designer of the top-level component the freedom to connect it to a pin or an internally generated reset signal, and to reset different parts of the logic independently -- for example, a bus interface would be connected to the reset pin on the bus, and the application logic behind that would be connected to a register that is addressable on the bus.

Most fabrics will have synchronous and asynchronous load and clear inputs on all the flipflops that can be connected to high-fanout nets, so writing code like

```
if ?? reset then
    index <= 0;
elsif rising_edge(clk) then
    ...
end if;
```

or

```
if rising_edge(clk) then
    if ?? reset then
        index <= 0;
    else
        ...
    end if;
end if;
```

doesn't cost extra resources.